# How do I save a Gensim model while ensuring forwards compatibility?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, gensim

I'm using the [save method](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html#gensim.models.phrases.Phraser.save) on the Gensim Phrases class to store a model for future use but if I update my version of Gensim, I have problems loading that model back in. For example, I get the following error when loading a model in Gensim 2.3.0 that was made in 2.2.0:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>()

~/Stuff/Sources/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/phrases.py in __init__(self, phrases_model)
    395         self.min_count = phrases_model.min_count
    396         self.delimiter = phrases_model.delimiter
--> 397         self.scoring = phrases_model.scoring
    398         self.phrasegrams = {}
    399         corpus = pseudocorpus(phrases_model.vocab, phrases_model.delimiter)

AttributeError: 'Phrases' object has no attribute 'scoring'
```

Is there a better way to ensure forwards compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `gensim` only a couple times and is a newbie, but judging by the [Change Log](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#230-2017-07-25), the [`scoring` attribute was introduced on a `Phrases`  class in 2.3.0](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/1464/files#diff-cb673cf37d57cdbaaa92b62f019a380dR171).

Now, from what I noticed in the github issues, when it comes to saving and loading the models, backwards compatibility is something that maintainers are trying to keep. It looks like the "missing scoring" attribute problem was [addressed in 3.1.0](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/commit/a5872fabb069925c89dcdeaff5ff569b28813ef6) - see the "backwards scoring compatibility when loading a Phrases class" comment and the related discussion in the [pull request](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/1573). The idea of the fix was basically to improve the `load()` method to [handle missing attributes and implicitly replacing them with the defaults](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/phrases.py#L485-L496) to avoid loading failures.

I think in 2.3.0 `gensim` had this [generic `SaveLoad` class for pickling/unpickling models](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/2.3.0/gensim/utils.py#L249) - as you can see, it is pretty much straightforward, no model-specific logic here.

I am though not sure if and how you can keep the models compatible between 2.2.0 and 2.3.0. I would open a new issue at the [`gensim` issue tracker](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues).

Comment: Oh, that's good to know. I updated to 3.1.0 but now I have a different compatibility error: AttributeError: 'Phrases' object has no attribute 'common_terms'

So if Gensim does intend to keep backwards compatibilty, I will just file a bug as you suggest. Cheers!

Comment: @Durand sure. Please cross-reference this discussion with the github issue - I would like to keep track of what is happening. Thanks!

Comment: @Durand I think you've just found an actual new issue - as I can see, the [`load()` method does not handle the missing `common_terms` atrribute](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/phrases.py#L465-L497). It should be handled as the `scoring` attribute during model loading.

Comment: Looks like there's some development on this issue [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/1568) so I guess I just have to wait now.